# NOT(~) vs NEGATION(!)

Tags: c++, c, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
   int i=-5;
   while(~(i))
   {
      cout<<i;
      ++i;
   }

 }
```

The output is -5,-4,-3,-2.
Shouldn't it print values till -1?Why is it only till -2.
And please explain me the difference between 'not' and 'negation' operators.When ever I write a program they were the source for bugs.

```
while(i)
```

I know that the loop condition will be true for positive and negative i's except 0.

```
while(!i) vs while(~i)
```

For what values of 'i' the above two loops get executed?

Comment: If you can't remember the difference between `!` and `~`, use `!`. It's almost always the one you will want. `~` is rarely necessary.

Comment: Tip that might be useful to you, since the correct answer was already posted.  For (modular) integer types, `~i == -i - 1`.

Comment: The operators actually do have names in C++: `!` is `not` and `~` is `compl`. (Lowercase, not uppercase)

Comment: @MSalters Or in C using [`iso646.h`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_alternative_tokens)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

When `i` gets to `-1`, the value of `~i` is `~-1`, or `0`, so the `while` loop stops executing. The `!` operator works because it does something completely different; it results in `1` for `0` values and `0` for all other values. `~` is a bitwise negation.

A little more in detail:

- `~` takes each bit in a number and toggles it. So, for example, 10010<sub>2</sub> would become 01101<sub>2</sub>
- `-1` is all ones in binary when a two's complement signed integer.
- `~0b…11111111` is `0`.

However:

- `!0` is `1`, `!anythingElse` is `0`
- `-1` is not `0`
- `!-1` is still `0`

And if you actually want to loop including `i == -1`, just use `while (i)` instead of `while (~i)`.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct about `i == -1` being the exit condition: your loop is equivalent to

```
int i=-5;
while(i != -1)
{
    cout<<i;
    ++i;
}
// i == -1 immediately after the loop
```

When written this way, it should be clear why `-1` is not printed the value is first printed, and only then incremented, that's why `-2` is the last value that you print.

The `!` operator, on the other hand, will produce `1` only when it is given a zero. That's why the loop would print `-1` when the `!` operator is used in the loop condition.

Answer (score 3):

'~' is the operator that : ~x = -x-1
and when i = -1, then ~i = 0.
if you wonder the value of ~i, you can just print them out:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
   int i=-5;
   for (int i = -5; i <= 3; i++)
   {
    cout<<i<<"  "<<(~i)<<endl;
   }
 }
```

and then you will find:
-5  4
-4  3
-3  2
-2  1
-1  0
0  -1
1  -2
2  -3
3  -4

Answer (score 2):

`!` is true/false logic flipping

`!` means `any nonzero becomes 0`, and `0 becomes 1`

eg1. `!0b1010 -> 0b0000`

eg2. `!0b0000 -> 0b0001`

eg3. `!0b1111 -> 0b0000`

generalised, `out = in?0:1`

while...

`~` is bit flipping

`~` means `flip each and every bit`

eg1. `~0b1010 -> 0b0101`

eg2. `~0b0000 -> 0b1111`

eg3. `~0b1111 -> 0b0000`

generalised, `out = in^0b1111`