# Could someone please explain step by step how i am getting -9 value as result?

Tags: java

I executed this `(~(1 << 3))` statement and I am getting `-9` as a result.

Statement : `(~(1 << 3))`

Result : `-9`

Comment: In general, `~x` is equal to `-x - 1`.  `1 << 3` is `8`, `-8 - 1` is `-9`.

Answer (score 4):

Numbers in computers are stored in [2's complement form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

Your original number is 1,which is `0...0001` in binary. I'm skipping bit 4 to 30 as they all will be zero (consider 32-bit system).

Doing `1 << 3` will yield `0...1000` i.e. +8. In simple terms, it means multiply 1 by `2^i`, where `i = 3` here.

Now, inverting this yields `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000` which is a negative number in 2's complement form.

To get the value of the number, drop the first 1(sign bit), invert the entire number again and add 1.

So, inverting again will give you `0...1000`. Add 1 to this, so `0...1001`.

This is the value of the number which is 9. And sign is negative because the first sign bit is 1.

Comment: Now, inverting this yields 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000 which is a negative number in 2's complement form.     when you are inverting 32 bit  why are you not inverting the last 4 bits ?

Answer (score 2):

`<<` is the `left-shift` operator, which in simple terms, when applied to a number, multiplies it by `2^i`, where `i` is the number of bits to be shifted, for example :

```
1 << 3 = 8  (multiply 1 by 2^3)
2 << 4 = 32 (multiply 2 by 2^4)
```

and `~` is the `NOT` operator, which takes each bit in a number and toggles it. In simple terms, `~x = -x - 1` For example :

```
~100102 = 011012
~8 = -9
```

Now coming to your question, `(~(1 << 3)) = (~8) = -9`. For more info, check this answer : [NOT(~) vs NEGATION(!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572181/not-vs-negation).

Comment: Could you explain how the system convert ~8 to -9 internally?

Comment: See the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572181/not-vs-negation @prashanth