# command not found followed by segmentation fault 11

Tags: c, bash

I was trying to make a program that would get inputs like

```
   1     833N619DL  ABQ           26     204     214    1250
   1    1125N660DL  ABQ           18     211     204    1250
   1    1589N678DL  ABQ           23     206     212    1250
   2     833N659DL  ABQ           18     204     194    1250
   2    1125N656DL  ABQ           23     211     210    1250
   2    1589N665DN  ABQ           19     206     212    1250
   3     833N686DA  ABQ           23     204     204    1250
   3    1125N692DL  ABQ           27     211     216    1250
   3    1589N635DL  ABQ           26     206     210    1250
   4     833N688DL  ABQ           21     204     206    1250
   4    1125N660DL  ABQ           18     211     221    1250
   4    1589N631DL  ABQ           28     206     209    1250
```

this data and and out put only the numbers from the input(excluding the column with numbers and alphabets mixed)

This is my program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXLINE 10000

char *itoa(int i);                  //convert integer to char array

main() {
    int temp= 0, i = 0, c, j = 0;
    char *a[MAXLINE];               //pointer array with uninitialized pointers

while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    if(isdigit(c))
        temp = 10 * temp + c - '0';
    else if(!isalpha(c)) {
        a[i] = itoa(temp); 
        ++i;

        if(c == '\n') {
            *a[i] = '\n';
            j++;
        }
    }

    printf("Data is\n");

    for(int n = 0; n <= j; n++)
        printf("%s\n", a[n]);
}

char *itoa(int i) {

    char *s;

    while(i % 10 != 0) {
        *s++ = i / 10;            //save to s
        i = i % 10;               //removed saved part from i
}

    return s;
}
```

I compiled it and gave the data above. I was supposed the press control-D to tell the program that I was done inputing(EOF), but the program responded with a segmentation fault 11, and right after that, the terminal started accepting my input as if I wrote them like this:

```
urw7RS:Desktop urw7rseeh8fr$        1    1125N660DL  ABQ           18     211     204    1250
```

The terminal told me that the command wasn't found. 
This is the output:

```
urw7RS:Desktop urw7rseeh8fr$ ./a.out
   1     833N619DL  ABQ           26     204     214    1250
   1    1125N660DL  ABQ           18     211     204    1250
   1    1589N678DL  ABQ           23     206     212    1250
   2     833N659DL  ABQ           18     204     194    1250
   2    1125N656DL  ABQ           23     211     210    1250
   2    1589N665DN  ABQ           19     206     212    1250
   3     833N686DA  ABQ           23     204     204    1250
   3    1125N692DL  ABQ           27     211     216    1250
   3    1589N635DL  ABQ           26     206     210    1250
   4     833N688DL  ABQ           21     204     206    1250
   4    1125N660DL  ABQ           18     211     221    1250
   4    1589N631DL  ABQ           28     206     209    1250
Segmentation fault: 11
urw7RS:Desktop urw7rseeh8fr$        1    1125N660DL  ABQ           18     211     204    1250
-bash: 1: command not found
urw7RS:Desktop urw7rseeh8fr$        1    1589N678DL  ABQ           23     206     212    1250
-bash: 1: command not found
urw7RS:Desktop urw7rseeh8fr$        2     833N659DL  ABQ           18     204     194    1250
-bash: 2: command not found
urw7RS:Desktop urw7rseeh8fr$        2    1125N656DL  ABQ           23     211     210    1250
-bash: 2: command not found
urw7RS:Desktop urw7rseeh8fr$        2    1589N665DN  ABQ           19     206     212    1250
-bash: 2: command not found
urw7RS:Desktop urw7rseeh8fr$        3     833N686DA  ABQ           23     204     204    1250
-bash: 3: command not found
urw7RS:Desktop urw7rseeh8fr$        3    1125N692DL  ABQ           27     211     216    1250
-bash: 3: command not found
urw7RS:Desktop urw7rseeh8fr$        3    1589N635DL  ABQ           26     206     210    1250
-bash: 3: command not found
urw7RS:Desktop urw7rseeh8fr$        4     833N688DL  ABQ           21     204     206    1250
-bash: 4: command not found
urw7RS:Desktop urw7rseeh8fr$        4    1125N660DL  ABQ           18     211     221    1250
-bash: 4: command not found
urw7RS:Desktop urw7rseeh8fr$        4    1589N631DL  ABQ           28     206     209    1250
-bash: 4: command not found
urw7RS:Desktop urw7rseeh8fr$
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The "command not found"  comes from the shell after your program has aborted with a segmentation fault. I guess you pasted the input with the mouse buffer and the leftover input can't be processed by the aborted program, so it gets pasted into the shell.

Comment: `char *a[MAXLINE];               //pointer array to store data` -->> `char *a[MAXLINE];               //pointer array with uninitialised pointers` And you are storing ints into them) `*a[i] = '\n';` is wrong, it assigns to an uninitialised pointer. `a[i] = itoa(temp);` :: ditto

Comment: I did copy it from a text file with the keyboard. Thanks

Comment: You never initialise or provide storage for `s` in itoa.

Comment: Indent your code..... @user441343

Comment: It is not clear how your progam is preocessing the given input. It's just handwritten code to parse and print integers. There are library functions for that.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, prefer `!isalpha(c)` to `~isalpha(c)`. The former operator is logical negation, the latter is bitwise complement. See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572181/not-vs-negation

Comment: Re: "I did copy it from a text file with the keyboard": A better approach is to have Bash *redirect* your program's standard input to come from the file: `./a.out < my_file.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the terminal is *interpreting* your data instead of processing it, so it tries to execut each line as if it were a command, and there's no such command as the numbers leading each line of your file. Are you sure you're executing your program and not the file containing your data?

Moreover, all your `char*` pointers to strings are not allocated, so you get `Segmentation fault`